# Dominating set of a graph and a dominating set of independent sets

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A dominating set of a graph is a minimal set of vertices such that all vertices of the graph are contained in the set and its neighbours.
An independent set is a set of vertices that no two vertices are connected by an edge.

I need to find a graph in which all independent sets are dominated by at most one vertex, and the size of a dominating set of the graph is $100$.

In all of my attemps I could not even find a graph with a dominatring set (of the graph) of size $3$ while all independent sets are dominated by at most one vertex.

What is a good approach to this problem?

Comment: I like the way you posed this question because you are not just interested in the solution, but the process of arriving at the solution. I believe I've just come up with a solution, but now it may take some time to explain how/why I arrived there...

Comment: Whoops; my answer wasn't actually an answer. More thought is required...

Comment: What stops you from taking a graph of $100$ isolated vertices with no edges?

Comment: A graph consisting only of 100 isolated vertices has an independent set that is not dominated by any single vertex: the vertex set itself!

Comment: @Bob1123 I read the condition as "for any independent set, there is at most one vertex dominating it". I guess with a stretch it could also mean, "for any independent set, there exists a vertex dominating it". Clarification would be nice.

Comment: does such a graph even exist?

Comment: Some clarifications on the definitions: $V$ is the set of vertices of a graph $G$. Let $N(S)$ denote all vertices that are adjacent to at least one vertex of $S$ and let $N′(S) = S ∪ N(S)$. 
We say that $S$ is a dominating set if $N′(S) ⊃ V$.
The independent domination number is the maximum over all independent sets $J$ in $G$, of the minimal size of a set $S$ such that $N(S) ⊃ J$ (not $N'(S)$).
I need to find a graph with independent domination number of $1$, while the smallest dominating set is of size $100$.

Comment: OK I think I got an answer. I found it on the internet and now that I know the answer it seems rather simple to come up with that. We need to look at the line graph of the hypergraph $\binom {[n^2]}n$. For example, if $n=2$ then this is the graph with vertices $12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 34$ and every two share an edge iff the vertices intersect. Notice that we need two vertices to dominate the graph, while every two non-adjacent vertices (independent set) are separated by at most one vertex.

Comment: @MishaLavrov ah I see my mistake. Thanks for the clarification.